# Is it possible to perform XML validation for expression bindings in VS Code?

Tags: sapui5

This would increase development productivity. Is there a VS Code extension that supports this type of UI5 (expression) binding validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, https://github.com/SAP/ui5-language-assistant/issues/82 is the only place that asks for expression binding validation (Give it a  there to indicate that the feature is needed).

I'll update this answer as soon as the feature is available.